# Restrict Membership Payments to Fixed Contribution Amounts in 4.7

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

Yo yo yo everyone, hello we're doing an upgrade from civi 4.0.5 >>> 4.7 and running into the following issue :

In civicrm older version 4.0.5 we are able to create fixed payment amounts as the only options available on the contribution page e.g. https://sitename.org/civicrm/admin/contribute/amount?reset=1&action=update&id=78

Previously on the live payment (contribution) page in 4.0.5 it would display, in a box, the minimum membership amount, i.e. "(contribute at least $_____ to be eligible for this membership" plus "Your _TYPE__ membership expired on___expiration date_____) but at same time we could restrict payment options to solely the "Fixed Contribution Options"

(without compelling the user to add automatically the minimum membership fee to it)

Note : Membership settings are configured as follows

1. Membership Section Enabled? Y
2. Default membership selected Y
3. Require Membership Signup Y
4. Separate Membership Payment N
5. Display Membership Fee Y

In other words , restrict the payment to only use what we configure in the fixed payment options

For the minimum membership amount set in membership type , we just want to display it as previous.

No matter how we play with the settings...we cannot get it back after upgrading to 4.7

Any idea or links as to what changed in civicrm 4.7 and why ?

And .. do we need to custom code to fix?

In Civi 4.0.5:
[image]

In Civi 4.7:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: It's a bit hard to envision what you're describing.  Could you please edit your question to include screenshots?  Hopefully you have a test copy of the old site (or it's available on archive.org), since the old site's screenshot will be more helpful.

Comment: Hey Jon thanks for taking a look. trying to add screen shots but it says we're not allowed to add any more links...is there another way to attach or send ? thanks..

Comment: Send them to me on https://chat.civicrm.org, I'm @junglebird there.  I'll get them added to the question.

Comment: @Jon G: Sir, we intend to remove the Membership radio button completely from the page in civicrm 4.7 as in civicrm 4.0. Can you help us with that??

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the exact thing you are experiencing, but I just found a strange behavior that required me to uncheck "Display Membership Fee" to get a Membership only contrib page without the "Additional Payment" option. I have to do further testing.

Comment: Ok we would be very curious to hear about that as we are testing our own for go live this weekend..thanks! H

Answer (score 1):

The screenshots don't match the settings you listed above (e.g. "Additional Payment" is set to "Yes") but assuming the question is, "How can I match the 4.7 screen to the 4.0 screen?" you can add a Price Set for Memberships.

- Go to **Memberships menu » New Price Set**.
- Fill in the required fields.  *Used For* should be set to **Membership**.
- On the *New Price Field* screen, set the *Input Field Type* to **Radio**.
- Create as many options as needed, setting the "Membership Type" to the "A" Membership.
- Go to the contribution page in question's *Membership* tab.
- Set the *Membership Price Set* to the set you just created and save.